# How to find the key of a parent using the forEach function?

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object in memory that looks like this:

```
let data = {
    12353: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfh7ahdk8: 14,
            eiefhsdoowen: 24,
            jaweufwvnw83: 54
        },
    14324: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfr7ahdk8: 16,
            eiefhsdsfsdf: 44,
            asgrega4ffef: 14
        },
    }
```

I'm trying to iterate over it using `forEach` on the `data` object and get the parent key (either `12353` or `14324`) like so:

```
data.forEach(values => {
    let parentKey = ??  //I tried Object.keys(values) but it gives me CurrentNumbers
}
```

Is there a way to get the key one level up?

Comment: what do you mean by one level up?

Comment: @Sajeetharan right now I'm getting the key "CurrentNumbers" but I would like to get the key "12353".  So the parent of CurrentNumbers

Comment: `data.forEach` does not work for the given object.

Comment: Your object is likely not correct - if it were, you could use Object.keys: `let data = {
  12353: {
    CurrentNumbers: {
      jiewfh7ahdk8: 14,
      eiefhsdoowen: 24,
      jaweufwvnw83: 54
    }
  },
  14324: {
    CurrentNumbers: {
      jiewfr7ahdk8: 16,
      eiefhsdsfsdf: 44,
      asgrega4ffef: 14
    },
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(data)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `forEach` over an object, because there is no `Object.prototype.forEach`. Instead, you can use a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to iterate over the properties of an object. Per the link to the MDN documentation:

> The **`for...in` statement** iterates over the enumerable properties of an object, in arbitrary order. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

Thus, using it, we can iterate over the properties `12353` and `14324`:

```js
let data = {
    12353: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfh7ahdk8: 14,
            eiefhsdoowen: 24,
            jaweufwvnw83: 54
        }
    },
    14324: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfr7ahdk8: 16,
            eiefhsdsfsdf: 44,
            asgrega4ffef: 14
        }
    }
}   
    
for(let x in data) {
    console.log(x);
}
```

<sup><sup>Your object literal had a few problems with braces. The above code is fixed</sup></sup>

The above code uses a `for...in` loop to loop through properties of `data` and store them into `x`. Once printing, the properties `12353` and `14324` are logged.

---

As [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan) suggested, you may even do:

```
console.log(Object.keys(data))
```

What this does is use [`Object.keys(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to return an array of `data`'s enumerable properties, `12353` and `14324`. Note that the returned array stores the properties as strings.

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.keys(data)))

Comment: @mplungjan edited. The JSON stringify isn't needed if you want an array of the enumerable properties

Comment: I used it since the console will show it in 4 or more lines instead of one

Comment: That does work to display the keys but then it looks like I don't have access to the children now?

Comment: @mattc19 Of course you have access. In the for-in loop you can use bracket notation to access the children.

Comment: @AndrewLi oh ok. So just use data['12353']

Comment: @mattc19 Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/js2gj6wb/2/ if the nested objects have common name `CurrentNumbers`. If not, just loop like `for(let currentNumbers in data[numbers])`

Answer (score 1):

While Andrew already answered the quetion,If you just want to retrieve the keys of objects you could just put,

```js
let data = {
    12353: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfh7ahdk8: 14,
            eiefhsdoowen: 24,
            jaweufwvnw83: 54
        }
    },
    14324: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfr7ahdk8: 16,
            eiefhsdsfsdf: 44,
            asgrega4ffef: 14
        }
    }
 }; 
 console.log(Object.keys(data));
```

you can also use **[`underscore.js`](http://underscorejs.org/)** and get the keys as below,

```
let data = {
    12353: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfh7ahdk8: 14,
            eiefhsdoowen: 24,
            jaweufwvnw83: 54
        }
    },
    14324: {
        CurrentNumbers: {
            jiewfr7ahdk8: 16,
            eiefhsdsfsdf: 44,
            asgrega4ffef: 14
        }
    }
 }; 
 console.log(_.keys(data));
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/y58j28ag/)**

Comment: I'm curious as to why you used underscore.js when the question doesn't even mention using it? Why include a library just for an operation like this?

Comment: There can be many answers for a question, this is just another way

Comment: Object.keys(data) without underscore

Comment: @mplungjan that is another answer :P